# SQL Get duplicate records from one table that exist in another table

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I want to get the records from **Table1** where it has more than on 1 record for same **Access Number**, but at the same time this **Access Number** should also be present in **Table2**.

Example :

Table1

```
Access Number

 - 1000
 - 1000
 - 1000
 - 2000
 - 3000
 - 4000
 - 5000
 - 5000
```

Table2

```
   Access Number    Value

 - 1000            - Test1
 - 2000            - Test2
 - 3000            - Test3
```

The result of the query should be 1000.

This is what i've got to so far, please suggest.

```
SELECT a.AccessNumber from Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b on b.AccessNumber = a.AccessNumber
Group by a.AccessNumber
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

**EDIT :**

I would also need a column value from Table2 along

```
 SELECT a.AccessNumber, b.Value from Table1 a
    JOIN Table2 b on b.AccessNumber = a.AccessNumber
    Group by a.AccessNumber
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

Comment: what is the issue on the result of your query?

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

I would use `exists`:

```
select t1.AccessNumber 
from Table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.AccessNumber = t1.AccessNumber)
group by t1.AccessNumber
having count(*) > 1;
```

This works even if you have duplicates in `table2`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this appears to be working, BTW what is the difference if i use HAVING COUNT(1) instead of HAVING COUNT(*). In either case the result is same.

Comment: @Maverick . . . They are pretty much the same.  If I were learning SQL today, I might encourage `COUNT(1)` or even `SUM(1)`.  However, I learned `COUNT(*)` and my fingers pretty much do it automatically.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Adding to that, please also check my Edit on question, i also need to get a column from Table2 along with the results

Comment: @Maverick . . . In that case, you'e changed the question and `join` is appropriate.

Comment: I agree. I absolutely need a Join, i managed to use it along with the exists but it also returns duplicates from Table2. Please suggest

Comment: @Maverick . . . I don't generally modify answers, when the question has changed in a substantial way that invalidates answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168876/discussion-between-maverick-and-gordon-linoff).

Answer (score 0):

-- Please try this code

```
Create table #table1 (Accessnumber int)
Create table #table2 (Accessnumber int)
go
truncate table #table1
insert into #table1 values 
 (1000)
 ,(1000)
 ,(1000)
 ,(2000)
 ,(3000)
 ,(4000)
 ,(5000)
 ,(5000)

 insert into #table2 values 
 (1000)
 ,(2000)
 ,(3000)

 select t1.Accessnumber, count(*)NoOfRecords
 from #table1 t1
 inner join #table2 t2 on t2.Accessnumber = t1.Accessnumber
 group by t1.Accessnumber
 having count(*)>1
```

Comment: No, i tried this, this returns the records from Table1 even if the count in Table 1 is just one. But I need only those records from Table1 whose count is greater than 1.

Comment: Hope you have missed having clause

Answer (score -1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to rank the Table1 query and join Table2 with result. Here is the sample query.

```
SELECT AccessNumber,RN 
FROM
      ( SELECT a.AccessNumber
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.accessNumber, ORDER BY A.accessNumber) AS RN  
        FROM  Table1 a
) O
JOIN  Table2 b on b.AccessNumber = o.AccessNumber
WHERE RN > 1
```